# Raspberry Pi 3 - omxplayer from python 2.7 - how to check if a video finished to play?

Tags: raspbian, python, pi-2, pi-3, omxplayer

I want to know if it's possible to check in omxplayer that it's finished to play a video file.

I use this code to start the omxplayer:

```
os.system("omxplayer -b /home/pi/Videos/file.mp4")
```

May be it is possible to run omxplayer so, that after playing the file it's closing itself and with polling to check if omxplayer process exists and if not -> to run the next file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Python OMXPlayer wrapper](https://github.com/willprice/python-omxplayer-wrapper) instead of **os.system()**.

Read [docs](http://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/genindex/) and example how to write simple script to run file. Read about [is_playing()](http://python-omxplayer-wrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/omxplayer/#omxplayer.player.OMXPlayer.is_playing) method, will be helpful.